# Eclipselink claims my entity has no primary key defined when using the jpa-schema-maven-plugin to generate migrations schemes

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink

I am using the io.github.divinespear:jpa-schema-maven-plugin:0.1.12 plugin to generate my sql scripts. This used to work beautifully, but has stopped working recently. The specific error message is:

```
[ERROR] Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: java.net.URLClassLoader@28a6301f
[ERROR] Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
[ERROR] Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [userService] failed.
[ERROR] Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7161] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
[ERROR] Exception Description: Entity class [class my.firm.integration.sp.usermanager.entity.PermissionEntity] has no primary key specified. It should define either an @Id, @EmbeddedId or an @IdClass. If you have defined PK using any of these annotations the
n make sure that you do not have mixed access-type (both fields and properties annotated) in your entity class hierarchy.
```

Some of my entities use a @MappedSuperclass, but this class does not define a primary key. I do not mix my access-types.

Because I have been working on this project for a while but seldom add new entities or change existing ones, I cannot pinpoint the time at which the plugin stopped working. Going back to previous commits has not changed the outcome and at this point I have to assume it is something else.

Here are an example entity, the related code and configurations:

PermissionEntity.java:

```
package my.firm.integration.sp.usermanager.entity;

import my.firm.integration.sp.userauthentication.dto.PermissionDTO;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "PERMISSIONS")
public class PermissionEntity extends VersionedEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "PERMISSION_ID")
    private String permissionId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Map<String, PermissionAttributeValueEntity> permissions;

    public PermissionDTO toDTO() {
        PermissionDTO dto = new PermissionDTO();
        dto.setId(id);
        dto.setPermissionDefinitionId(permissionId);
        dto.setFields(permissions
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().toDTO())));
        return dto;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="userService" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="jdbc"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="none"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.index-foreign-keys" value="true"/>
            <!-- <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

eclipselink-orm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.6"
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_orm_2_6.xsd">

    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <tenant-discriminator-column name="TENANT_ID" column-definition="VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL"
                context-property="eclipselink.tenant-id" length="64" />
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>

    <entity class="my.firm.integration.sp.usermanager.entity.UserEntity">
        <multitenant type="SINGLE_TABLE">
        </multitenant>
    </entity>
    <entity class="my.firm.integration.sp.usermanager.entity.RoleEntity">
        <multitenant type="SINGLE_TABLE">
        </multitenant>
    </entity>
    <entity class="my.firm.integration.sp.usermanager.entity.PermissionEntity">
        <multitenant type="SINGLE_TABLE">
        </multitenant>
    </entity>
    <entity class="my.firm.integration.sp.usermanager.entity.PermissionAttributeValueEntity">
        <multitenant type="SINGLE_TABLE">
        </multitenant>
    </entity>
    <entity class="my.firm.integration.sp.usermanager.entity.UserLockoutEntity">
        <multitenant type="SINGLE_TABLE">
        </multitenant>
    </entity>
    <entity class="my.firm.integration.sp.usermanager.entity.IpLockoutEntity">
        <multitenant type="SINGLE_TABLE">
        </multitenant>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

The configured plugin in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.github.divinespear</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa-schema-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.12</version>
    <configuration>
        <scriptAction>create</scriptAction>
        <dialect>dummy</dialect>
        <databaseProductName>${database.productName}</databaseProductName>
        <persistenceUnitName>userService</persistenceUnitName>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

When I use this maven command: `mvn -Ddatabase.productName="Microsoft SQL Server" jpa-schema:generate`, I expect the schema to be placed in the `target/generated-schema` folder, but instead the above error occurs.

Comment: The class in the error message doesn't match the package for the one you show. class de.escriba.integration.sp.usermanager.entity.PermissionEntity vs package my.firm.integration.sp.usermanager.entity implies you have more then one PermissionEntity within your persistence unit and the one in the de.escriba.integration.sp.usermanager.entity package isn't correct.

Comment: @Chris I'm afraid that's on me. I was trying to obfuscate my firm, but I suppose that went rather poorly. The actual package is de.escriba